# Updating POSTGRES version on scotchbox

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

** EDIT **

I have found a great thread explaining how here: 
https://gist.github.com/johanndt/6436bfad28c86b28f794

**************** Original Question Below ************************

I have been using scotchbox(v2.5) as my development environment for some time, and I really like how easy it was to deploy and start working with. I have come to a point where I need to update the version of Postgres (currently 9.3) to at least 9.5 to get the `INSERT....ON CONFLICT` functionality. I have searched but am still left with little idea how to do this.

One thing that will make this much easier is that I **do not need to keep any existing data**. I would like for the new v9.5+ database to directly replace the existing v9.3 and operate as if I downloaded scotchbox with it preinstalled.

Comment: It appears that scotchbox is just an Ubuntu, so you should be able to remove the old version using the `apt-get remove postgresql-9.3` then `apt-get install postgresql-9.6`. If 9.6 is not in the Ubuntu repository, see here: here https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/ for an explanation on how to add the Postgres repository to the system

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply @a_horse_with_no_name. I am reading the doc and honestly don't feel fully confident in what I am doing, and thus I am humbly requesting some extra hand-holding.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_nameI followed your directions -- removed my old version and installed 9.6. Seemed to be successful. But now do I have to "point" scotchbox at it? My Postico (psql client) can no longer connect to the database like I had it before through ssh